# How to use jasper parameters in a custom JRDatasource?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, datasource

I'm using Jaspersoft Studio 6.11 with Jasper Server 7.5.0.

I want to create a datasource which use report parameters.
My datasource is based on this example:
https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/how-create-and-use-jrdatasource-adapter

```
public class MyImplementation implements JRDataSource {

//This should be initialized from report parameter $P{param}= "Frank,Joseph,Marco,Carl,Lenny,Homer,Teodor,Leopold"
private static String param;   

private static String[] nameArray;

private static final Integer[] ageArray = {50,30,40,46,44,26,32,21};

private int counter = -1;

private HashMap<String, Integer> fieldsNumber = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

private int lastFieldsAdded = 0;

@Override
public boolean next() throws JRException {
    if (counter<nameArray.length-1) {
        counter++;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public Object getFieldValue(JRField jrField) throws JRException {
    Integer fieldIndex;
    if (fieldsNumber.containsKey(jrField.getName()))
        fieldIndex = fieldsNumber.get(jrField.getName());
    else {
        fieldsNumber.put(jrField.getName(), lastFieldsAdded);
        fieldIndex = lastFieldsAdded;
        lastFieldsAdded ++;
    }
    if (fieldIndex == 0) return nameArray[counter];
    else if (fieldIndex == 1) return ageArray[counter];
    return "";
}


public static JRDataSource getDataSource(){
    nameArray = param.split(",")
    return new MyImplementation();
}
}
```

`String param` should be initialized with report parameter $P{param} value.
How to do that?
How to use report parameters in Custom DataSource?

Answer (score 1):

The most common way to do this is to create a constructor and pass the parameter(s) in this.

First remove all your `static` modifiers both because you do not need them but also so that you can execute multiple reports contemporary from different threads (even if you are not currently doing this)

Your constructor would be

```
public MyImplementation(String param){
    this.param = param;
}
```

And when you use it in jrxml you pass the parameter

```
<dataSourceExpression>
    <![CDATA[new my.package.name.MyImplementation($P{param})]]>
</dataSourceExpression>
```